# What is the browser support for Image Element constructor in html?

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom

What is the browser support for [Image Element constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) in html?

Comment: It wasn't in specs before HTML5 because there were no DOM specifications previously, but `Image()` is here since a very long time... The oldests UAs I could test are IE8 and FF3.2a and it was already there. So this leads to *"why this question in 2017 ?"*

Comment: @Kaiido I have been reading canvas totorial lately. I had not seen `Image()` before. And when I tried to look for browser compatibility on caniuse.com I couldn't find it. Hence the question :-)

Comment: Well I think nobody references it because it's supported since Enigma.

Answer (score 2):

You can test it yourself here:

https://w3c-test.org/html/semantics/embedded-content/the-img-element/Image-constructor.html

Current versions of Firefox, Chrome, and Edge pass all those tests. Current Safari passes all of them except just one: the “NamedConstructor creates the correct object structure” test, which is just a test that checks for equality of `Image.prototype.__proto__` to `HTMLElement.prototype`. But I think that’s very unlikely to affect anything you’d want to actually do with it in your own  code, so it’s a non-problem in practice.

Comment: I don't have safari. That's why I can't test on all possible browsers.

Comment: It works in Safari, as the answer indicates. I tested it.

Comment: Is there an online source that emulates all browsers to test html features?

Comment: @user31782 https://wptdashboard.appspot.com/ has test results from browsers for lots of specs/features, from running the tests in actual browsers. https://saucelabs.com/ and https://www.browserstack.com provide ways you run tests in other browsers/versions remotely